# Angular Material Mat-video caption button not showing on any browser

Tags: angular-material

I have created video player using mat-video angular material tag.

My video has been working properly but my track tag not showing caption button on any browser.

code:

```
<mat-video src="../assets/video.mp4" > 
    <track matVideoTrack src="../assets/dw_trailer_low.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" default /> 
</mat-video>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Please update it with more information along with what you are currently trying and what specific issues/errors you are getting.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent <mat-video src="../assets/video.mp4" >
    <track
      matVideoTrack
      src="../assets/dw_trailer_low.vtt"
      kind="subtitles"
      srclang="en"
      label="English"
      default
    />
  </mat-video> Video showing properly on browser but caption/subtitles button not showing on any browser .Hope you understand now.

Comment: "Your question doesn't make much sense. Please update it..." Can you remove your latest comment and put the information in your question instead? :)

Comment: @dnyaneshwarsuryawanshi, is your `.vtt` file loading or showing 404 in developer tools ?

Comment: @Akber Iqbal.vtt file loading and showing content also but only caption(cc) button not showing.